# Multiple Conditional Effects Plots

Tags: r

I have the following linear model:
`y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (x1*x2) + (x1*x3) + (x2*x3)`

`x1` and `x2` are continuous and `x3` is a dummy variable.

I can't seem to figure out how to graph, side by side, conditional effects plots so such that I can examine the following:

- Conditional effect of `x1`|`x2` on `y` when (also conditional on) `x3`=0
- Conditional effect of `x1`|`x2` on `y` when `x3`=1

I have looked through the documentation for a number of R packages that I have used in the past to make effects plots and 'scoured' the internet, but can't seem to find the answer for this particular problem.  I feel like I have seen something like this before that involved 'fake' data, but haven't been able to find it again.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know a package for automating this task, but you can do it yourself with couple key strokes. Notice, R is smart enough to understand that

```
  model <- lm(y~x1*x2*x3,data) = to y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (x1*x2) + (x1*x3) + (x2*x3).
```

For understanding the interaction, you want plot the fits. The problem is that you have three independent variables, so you would really need a 4d plot, which is rather difficult to draw. That's been said, an alternative is to simply plot the fits against x1 and x2 in two separate plots, one for each level of x3, your dummy variable. Let's see it in practice:

```
set.seed(1)
obs <- data.frame(x3=sample(c("A","B"),size=100,replace=TRUE),
                  x2=sample(1:10,size=100,replace=TRUE),
                  x1=sample(1:10,size=100,replace=TRUE),
                  y=rnorm(100))

model <- lm(y~x1*x2*x3,data=obs)

anova(update(model,.~.-x1:x2:x3),model)


fit.A <- data.frame(x3="A",x2=rep(1:10,10),x1=rep(1:10,each=10))
fit.A$pred <- predict(model,newdata=fit.A)
fit.B <- data.frame(x3="B",x2=rep(1:10,10),x1=rep(1:10,each=10))
fit.B$pred <- predict(model,newdata=fit.B)
par(mfrow=c(1,2),mai=c(0,0.1,0.2,0)+.02)

persp(x=1:10,y=1:10,z=matrix(fit.A$pred,nrow=10,ncol=10,byrow=TRUE),
xlab="x2",ylab="x1",zlab="fit",main="x3 = A",zlim=c(-.8,1.1))
persp(x=1:10,y=1:10,z=matrix(fit.B$pred,nrow=10,ncol=10,byrow=TRUE),
xlab="x1",ylab="x2",zlab="fit",main="x3 = B",zlim=c(-.8,1.1))
```

[image]

Another way is to use the `wireframe(y ~ x1 * x2 | x3)` function from the package `lattice` or the `effects` package.